# Scala JSON Writes with calculated values

Tags: scala, playframework

We were serializing a model using Play's JSON Serialisation.

```scala
case class Foo(
    var id: Long,
    var birthday: Date,
    [...]
)
object Foo {
  implicit val fooFormat: OFormat[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

However we want to add some calculated values, for example:

```
case class Foo(
    ...
) {
    def age: Int = 32
}
```

In order to include the age in the Serialisation, it seems we have to duplicate all the field names by writing out a full Writes/unapply method:

```
implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
    (JsPath \ "birthday").write[Date] and
    [...]
    (JsPath \ "age").write[Int]
)(unlift(Foo.unapply_extended))

def unapply_extended(a: Foo): Option[(Long,Date,[...],Int)] = Some(( a.id, a.birthday, [...], a.age))

implicit val fooReads = Json.reads[Foo]
```

Is there a way to include the calculated age value in JSON serialisation without having to re-enumerate the same case class fields/types several times over?  When there are a lot of fields it quickly becomes unmanageable, and all the information is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box I don't think it is possible as generated codecs optimize for common use case (case classes and its fields). But you can derive codecs and tune their behavior afterwards using [transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonTransformers).

```
case class Foo(
    ...
) {
    def age: Int = 32
}
object Foo {
  implicit val fooFormat: OFormat[Foo] = {
    val derived = Json.format[Foo] // majority of work done here

    // here we just modify output of writer to add that one field
    OFormat(
      r = derived,
      w = foo => Json.writes[Foo].transform { json: JsObject =>
        json.transform((__ \ 'age).json.put(JsNumber(foo.age))).getOrElse(json)
      }.writes(foo)
    )
  }
}
```

You could save a line or two if you derive Reads and Writes separately

```
object Foo {
  implicit val fooFormat: OFormat[Foo] = OFormat(
    r = Json.reads[Foo],
    w = foo => Json.writes[Foo].transform { json: JsObject =>
      json.transform((__ \ 'age).json.put(JsNumber(foo.age))).getOrElse(json)
    }.writes(foo)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks really promising. I haven't quite got it compiling yet, and reading thru the docs I got lost in a few places. I think JSNumber should become JsNumber, and I added all the imports from the linked docs and `import play.api.libs.json.{JsNumber, OFormat, Writes, __}`, but I get: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'OFormat'` and `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'transform'`.  I think i'm getting lost with the part with the `__` and literal symbol part (`'age`).

Comment: You can use `"age"` instead of `'age` (symbol literal). I fixed a few things in code, try now.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I now can't get past `value writes is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]`, for both versions, and with age as a string or a symbol literal.

Comment: Try now, I tested it in REPL so it should compile

Comment: Amazing thankyou! That was returning only the age, but I altered it and got it returning all the defualt fields plus the age by doing: `w = foo => Json.writes[Foo].transform { json: JsObject => {json + ("age" -> JsNumber(foo.age))}}.writes(foo)` Thanks so much, this is going to cut hundreds of lines of code and make things much more readable.

For other readers, note this can also be used to overwrite select existing fields, eg  `w = foo => Json.writes[Foo].transform { json: JsObject => {json + ("birthday" -> JsString(foo.birthday.toGMTString))}}.writes(foo)`